# Loading PNG images in react native

Tags: react-native

I am having this weird issue in react-native when using expo on my phone. Some images appear and some do not.

All the images appear when I run it via the browser

Running the expo optimise command breaks most of the images and they not longer appear

I tried to make some of my images smaller but the new pngs will not display on my phone (android)

Its very weird and doesnt make much sense

What could be the issue?

I am importing images like this

```
import logo from "../Graphics/logo.png"

 <Image
          source={logo}
          style={{ width: 71,  height:50 }}
        />
```

I made a quick app to demo the issue but now it doesnt even work in the browser?

https://github.com/LuptonM/PNGIssue

I did tried the require and it didnt make a difference.

I also tried android:largeHeap="true" and made no difference

Edit: As an update the pictures are now showing. I have no idea why. Its very weird

Comment: could you share reproducible code so I can give a shot on my computer

Comment: @Ninja47 I made an example repo (see updated question). Some reason I can't get any of the images to show in the browser now. Very confusing. 

In my actual app it just seemed that it didnt like some images and it didnt seem to matter how big they were